# QGIS-QField Form mode: How do I export/register in JPEG/PDF?

Tags: qgis, qfield, widget, attribute-form

I used the QField app to take data on the field with a customize form made with the Attribute Form and different type of widget. Now, back at the office, I exported my data on QGIS and I want to register my form in JPEG or PDF and print it, but I am not able to export/register it. All I can do is take a screenshot and then print it.

Is there a way to export/register it?

Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: If you're okay with it not looking exactly the same, you could set up a layout in Print Layout with the Atlas set to your data layer, and have two columns for the field name and field values respectively. Field names would just be simple text boxes; field values would be text boxes with an expression referring to the value (eg "site", "date", etc.), except for your image; use an image item and a data defined override for the image source to point to the image path as in the form. Once it's all set up export the atlas and you get one page/image per feature.